# Pop up Arabic/Urdu custom keyboard on Edittext Issue

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am working on app where i use **Urdu Custom Keyboard** its work fine but the problem is that when i type any-word e.g. (سلام), cursor become not works at mid character for example cut/copy/paste or deleting (ا) character from the mid from word are not work.
i uses rough technique just appending characters but is also work fine.

**For taping any alphabetic**

```
private void addText(View v) {
        // String b = "";
        // b = (String) v.getTag();
        // urdu_word.setText(b);
        if (isEdit == true) {
            String b = "";
            b = (String) v.getTag();
            if (b != null) {
                Log.i("buttonsOnclick", b);
                // adding text in Edittext
                mEt.append(b);
            }
        }
    }
```

**For back button tapping**

```
private void isBack(View v) {
        if (isEdit == true) {
            CharSequence cc = mEt.getText();
            if (cc != null && cc.length() > 0) {
                {
                    mEt.setText("");
                    mEt.append(cc.subSequence(0, cc.length() - 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Here the screenshot clear my problem to you people**
[image]

**I used a lot of library and code from github but don't catch good idea**

1) **[Keyboard-1](https://github.com/siddhpuraamitr/Hindi-Keyboard)**
[image]

2) **[Keyboard-2](https://github.com/jbak/Jbak-Keyboard)**
[image]

3) **[Keyboard-3](https://github.com/viizki/SafeKeyboard)**
[image]

4) **[Keyboard-4](https://github.com/jmejiaa/qsearch)**

i checked all these keyboard and more from libs, have same cursor issue, how to manage fully my custom keyboard by deleting character from mid and copy my written text copy paste like normal keyboard with EditText, thanks in advance all of you :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks God** i solved my issue using simple logic.

**For back button**

```
private void isBack(View v) {
        // char[] tempChar = null;
        if ((mEt.getText().toString().length() > 0)) {
            int temp = mEt.getSelectionEnd() - 1;
            if (temp >= 0) {
                mEt.setText((mEt.getText().toString()
                        .substring(0, mEt.getSelectionEnd() - 1).concat(mEt
                        .getText()
                        .toString()
                        .substring(mEt.getSelectionEnd(),
                                mEt.getText().length()))));
                mEt.setSelection(temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

**For adding any character**

```
private void addText(View v) {
        int temp = mEt.getSelectionEnd();
        if (temp >= 0) {
            String b = "";
            b = (String) v.getTag();

            mEt.setText((mEt.getText().toString()
                    .substring(0, mEt.getSelectionEnd()) + b.concat(mEt
                    .getText().toString()
                    .substring(mEt.getSelectionEnd(), mEt.getText().length()))));
            mEt.setSelection(temp + 1);
        }
    }
```

**for copy paste i added few lines code to EditText**

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/xEt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextshape"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```